# Pdf printout from Sunmi V1 device

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I need to take pdf printout from sunmi V1 device. Tried to take printout from acrobat reader but it is not displaying any printers.

1. Created an App in Ionic and converted the data into pdf.
2. From the generated pdf, trying to take printout. Printers are not visible.
3. Also installed cordova printer plugins, but they are also converting to pdf but not taking printouts.
4. When I tried to take printout through testing app provided by Sunmi, it is working fine.

Comment: have you tried other  devices? perhaps its an issue with acrobat.

Comment: Got information from Sunmi support that pdf printing is not possible, so took the printout with cordova-sunmi-inner-printer plugin using ionic2 app.